# Worklight 6.1.0.1 application builder crawls showing "Worklight application builder: (20%)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am having trouble deploying the app on to the worklight developerment server (Liberty profile).
Starting the eclipse from command line with -clean option did not help me. My configuration is

- Eclipse Kepler SR2 Java EE - 32 bit version
- Java 7 32 bit version
- worklight plugin 6.1.0.01
- Windows 7, 32G RAM, 512g SSD, core i7

I don't have any proxy network settings.

Whenever I select  -> righ click -> Run As -> Run on WorkLight Development Server, the build process is taking very long time, approximately 30 mins. out of which almost entire time is spent at "Worklight application builder: (20%)

Comment: Kill the Java process and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that this happens because of the Java process.

My suggest to you is to kill the Java process running in your system followed by re-starting Eclipse. Then, try to start the server and repeat the Run As... steps.

Comment: killing java did not solve the issue. I have both 32 bit and 64 bit java running on my machine. However for the workspace where the issue is being faced, configured 32 bit java.

Comment: We have found that the issue was more to do with Encryption in the laptop and the virus scanner configuration. Thanks.